Error in file(fn, "rb") : cannot open the connection
I want to buffer some bioclimatic variables with the following code. I'm using R 4.4.1 on a windows 11 22H2 PC 64bit.
# test buffersizes
results <- lapply(buffersizes, function(buffer_distance) {
  buffers <- buffer(occ.thinned.sp, width = buffer_distance)
  bioclim_values <- extract(envs_all.crop, buffers, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
  return(list(buffer_size = buffer_distance, values = bioclim_values))
})

print(results)

But I get this Error:
Error in file(fn, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(fn, "rb") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpErQYOu\raster\r_tmp_2024-08-06_163252.605407_8724_05039.gri': No such file or directory

I know that R is trying to load a temporary file which is not at the known path. The path itself doesn't exist. I tried many things including recreating the temp dir, but nothing worked even if I create that path, automatically or manually:
# check if temp folder is working
temp.dir <- ifelse(!dir.exists(tempdir()),
                   dir.create(tempdir(), recursive = TRUE),
                   FALSE)
tempdir()

I know that there are many solutions out there but none worked for me.
Can anyone help please?

This error seems specifically related to the raster package.
Possibly, data is saved to the temp folder you mentioned, but is removed later.
A solution that was suggested earlier is writing the data to a permanent file using writeRaster.
See Can not open created raster in R and Can not open created raster in R .
